# Animating TextView's leftDrawable using ObjectAnimator

Tags: android, animation, drawable

I would like to animate `leftDrawable` of a `TextView`, I tried the following:

```
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(drawable, "rotation", 0f, 360f).setDuration(300).start();
button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(drawable, null, null, null);
```

But it doesn't seem to animate, in the past I've used `AnimationDrawable` and it works by putting several drawables in a `<animation-list>`, but apk size is a concern so I'm trying to avoid having multiple assets to achieve this.

Please let me know if I've done something wrong or this is not achievable using `ObjectAnimator`.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you can get something from here!!!   http://chiuki.github.io/advanced-android-textview/#/

Comment: first of all you have to make sure that `drawable` object has `rotation` property, by default `Drawable` doesn't have such property

Comment: @pskink thanks, so I think this is not achievable using `ObjectAnimator` and `Drawable`. Make your comment an answer and I will accept it :)

Comment: it is possible: use `RotateDrawable` and manually call `setLevel` or try (untested) to use "level" property of `RotateDrawable`

Comment: ok tested that: you can use `"level"` property of `RotateDrawable`

Comment: @pskink like this? `ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(drawable, "level", 0f, 360f).setDuration(500).start();`, it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try this:

```
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    Drawable left = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rotate);
    tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(left, null, null, null);
    final ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(left, "level", 0, 10000).setDuration(1000);
    View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick ");
            animator.start();
        }
    };
    tv.setOnClickListener(listener);
    tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    tv.setTextSize(48);
    tv.setText("click me");
    setContentView(tv);
```

res/drawable/rotate.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromDegrees="0" android:toDegrees="720">
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
</rotate>
```

Comment: you are welcome, see other `Drawable` types to achieve different animations like `ClipDrawable`, `ScaleDrawable` etc...

Comment: You can also set the drawable in the rotate tag as attribute `android:drawable`, and in fact you must if it's not a bitmap, e.g. if it's a vector drawable. I had to do this, but the rest worked well, thanks!

Comment: @digithree yes i know <rotate> tag syntax

Comment: can someone tell me what the level property is ??

Comment: @PembaTamang see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#setLevel(int)

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is you call the animation to start before the drawable is drawn.
Try replace the order of the lines. Maybe you could add some delay.

Comment: Actually if the drawable had property of rotation you could had use ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder that can work on Drawable. Why don't you separate between the TextView and the Image so you could put the drawable inside ImageView and rotate the ImageView itself?

Comment: The button is actually a custom view and is used everywhere, so adding a `ProgressBar` would mean I have to wrap two of them together in another parent layout and replace the current one everywhere. It wasn't intended to be animated in the first place so I didn't wrap it in the first place.