# Animating non-view objects in Android

Tags: java, android, android-animation, material-design, objectanimator

After reading the documentation on PropertyAnimator, it seems like we can animate every object as long as that one of the following is fulfilled,

- Add the setter method to the class if you have the rights to do so.
- Use a wrapper class that you have rights to change and have that wrapper receive the value with a valid setter method and forward it to the original object.
- Use ValueAnimator instead.

I'm trying to animate on a MenuItem's Drawable or a StateListDrawable in a menu. Since drawables do not contain the setter method, I was wondering if anyone had used the ValueAnimator for translation animation could provide some examples.

Comment: there is a ton of examples. here is one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31130929/animating-textviews-leftdrawable-using-objectanimator

Answer (score 0):

```
ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1);
animator.setDuration(300);
animator.setInterpolator(new CycleInterpolator(3));
animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        label.setTranslationX(((Float) animation.getAnimatedValue()) * 20);
    }
});
animator.start();
```

ValueAnimator is very simple and can be used to animate anything. You just have to update values you need and invalidate views manually in each frame of animation. The above animation shakes a label three times.

Comment: Thanks! This works when we're allowed to update values and invalidate views in the object that we want to animate on. What happens when it's a built-in MenuItem? Is creating a wrapper class that wraps menuItem necessary?

Comment: Drawables have a build-in method for refreshing their parents. Just animate that drawable and call invalidateSelf() when needed.