# How can I rotate my DrawableLeft in my button?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to have a loading icon that spins in a circle.
My icon is a drawableLeft

I currently have it setup as an `AnimationDrawable`:

```
AnimationDrawable ad = (AnimationDrawable)run.getCompoundDrawables()[0];
ad.start();
```

Which is basically cycling through 4 different version of the bitmap:

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_load" android:duration="400" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_load2" android:duration="400" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_load" android:duration="400" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_load2" android:duration="400" />
```

However, it is not a smooth animation.
How can I make it rotate rather than cycle though different bitmaps?

Thanks

Comment: Could you use `Animation` instead?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31133449/2252830)

Comment: @pskink thank you!!! I hadn't seen that answer. That worked perfectly. :)